# Wildcard on wget to http download last release version

Tags: http, download, version, wildcard, wget

Imagine (as John Lenon would) that I am coding a script to download, let's say, the last version of KeePassTrueCrypt plugin.

It is a pain to update for the last release just because the URL contains the version number instead of simply 'last release' or a PPA, so I am using a wildcard. This is my try:

```
wget -r --no-parent -A "KeepassTrueCryptMount_v**.plgx.7z" https://bitbucket.org/schalpat/keepasstruecryptmount/downloads/
```

But 1) It only downloads index.html and robots.txt instead of the file 2) It is not specified to download the last version (max function?).

I appreciate any help. Cheers,

Answer (score 1):

The files you are trying to download are hosted on another domain named **amazonaws.com**.
So you could try these options to Download from another domains. because ***Wget’s recursive retrieval normally refuses to visit hosts different than the one you specified on the command line.***

> `-H` The ‘-H’ option turns on host spanning, thus allowing Wget’s recursive run to visit any host referenced by a link.
>
> `-D` The ‘-D’ option allows you to specify the domains that will be followed, thus limiting the recursion only to the hosts that belong to
>   these domains. Obviously, this makes sense only in conjunction with
>   ‘-H’

Comment: I really thought it was hosted on bitbucket. Nevertheless I tried

`wget -r -l1 --no-parent -A.plgx.7z -H https://bitbucket.org/schalpat/keepasstruecryptmount/downloads/ -D amazonaws.com`

Comment: and only index.html is downloaded. Without -D, logically, every link is downloaded.

Comment: you can make wget more realistic by using their other options. such as referer, cookies, useragent, etc...